# Inlining a script using macro

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I am working with a script engine, and I'd like to be able to do something like this or similar:

```
const char* script = SOME_MACRO(
    function foo() {
        print "bar";
    }
    foo();
)
OS* engine = OS::create();
engine->eval(script);
```

What would be a good way to achieve this?

I know that for multiline macros, I'd need `\` at the end of the line, and if possible, I'd like to avoid using a bunch of quoted strings, since my script might get quoted strings too, and id like to preserve line numbers.

Is there a good way to do so?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need macros. You can use raw string literals.

```
const char* script = R"SCRIPT_DELIMITER(
    function foo() {
        print "bar";
    }
    foo();
)SCRIPT_DELIMITER";
```

You can replace `SCRIPT_DELIMITER` with any delimiter you want, up to 16 characters, with no parentheses, backslashes or spaces, and the sequence `)YOUR_DELIMITER"` can not appear in your string (because it is used to terminate it).